# Combinations of two non-consecutive items

Tags: python, list, combinations

Given a list, how can I get all combinations between two non-consecutive items?

For example, for input `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` how can I get the output `[(1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,4), (2,5), (3,5)]`?

I'm not interested in `(1,2)`, `(2,3)`, `(3,4)` or `(4,5)` because they are consecutive (i.e. next to each other) in the list, but everything else I'm interested.

What's the most idiomatic way to do this in Python?

Comment: `consecutive` means next to each other in the list or the number which is immediately after, in the natural numbers?

Comment: @thefourtheye Thank you for your help. By consecutive I meant next to each other in the list. The list may not even be numbers, I just thought it was easier to visualize. I'll add something to the question to clear it up.

Comment: Have a took at the `itertools` and choose the function you need: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html You might have to filter them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [(a, b) for i, a in enumerate(lst) for b in lst[i+2:]]
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5)]
```

Comment: A tiny optimization: `enumerate(lst[:-2])`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Mmh, I don't like it. And I don't believe that it's an optimization. I think it's *worse*. Yes, you prevent my last two iterations, but their `lst[i+2:]` is empty, so it saves almost nothing. And it comes at the cost of another copy of almost the entire list, which also takes some time and which takes memory the whole time.

Comment: It would play a bigger role for `k≈n` - and e.g. if these were `numpy` arrays rather than lists which don't copy upon slicing.

Comment: Anyway, here are hard numbers (yours/mine, for a list of `1000`): for `k=2` - `175ms`/`178ms`, for `k=900` - `1.96ms`/`1.47ms`; for NumPy arrays, `258ms`/`265ms` and `5.6ms`/`2.8ms`, correspondingly.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thanks, I always like hard numbers :-). I get similar ratios, testing it like `timeit('[(a, b) for i, a in enumerate(lst[:-899]) for b in lst[i+900:]]', 'lst = range(1000)', number=10000)` (I also like to see how the hard numbers were gotten). Is that the generalization you mean with your "k"? I'm not at all surprised that your way is better there with large "k", but that's not what the question here asks about, so I'll still stick with my original.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly "idiomatic" way not using any modules, which is more efficient than some other implementations since every trip through the loop is used--no rejected possibilities.

```
r = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [(r[i], r[j]) for i in range(len(r)-2) for j in range(i+2, len(r))]
print(c)
```

This gives

```
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5)]
```

It is not completely idiomatic, since it loops on indices rather than values, but your restriction regarding the positions in the list rather than the values makes that fairly necessary. If you want a generator rather than a list, replace the outer brackets with parentheses.

Comment: This is basically an optimization (at the cost of readability) of [@StefanPochman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438676/combinations-of-two-non-consecutive-items/40438842#40438842) which avoids copying the list. You can get more speedup by using `xrange`. Due to `range`s being much slower than C loops though, it actually works _slower_ than @StefanPochman's answer: `270ms` vs `174ms` for a list of size 1000 on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the combinations with non-consecutive numbers from the list:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list(filter(lambda x: lst.index(x[1]) - lst.index(x[0]) > 1, combinations(lst,2)))

[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5)]
```

This compares the indices of the two numbers in a given combination and makes sure that the difference of their indices is greater than 1.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generalized solution for r-length combinations avoiding consecutive elements. It gets all index [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for an appropriately shorter list and then spreads out each combination's indexes. For example for r=3, any combination (x,y,z) turns into used indexes x+0, y+1, z+2.

```
from itertools import combinations

def non_consecutive_combinations(lst, r):
    return [tuple(lst[j+i] for i, j in enumerate(combi))
            for combi in combinations(range(len(lst)-r+1), r)]
```

Demo for r=2:

```
>>> non_consecutive_combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5)]
```

Demo for r=3:

```
>>> non_consecutive_combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3)
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 5, 7), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 5, 7), (3, 5, 7)]
```

A simplified version just for pairs:

```
>>> [(lst[i], lst[j+1]) for i, j in combinations(range(len(lst)-1), 2)]
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5)]
```